# Browser extension to suggest forums, tailor questions, and post questions for AIs

Tags: stack-exchange, reddit

I am using AIs, such as OpenAI's Copilot and Phind, for development purposes. These Artificial Idiots sometimes provide incorrect or incomplete answers, and in such cases, human experts have an advantage. As a result, I need to ask questions on online forums like Stack Exchange sites or subreddits.

However, formulating questions for these sites is more time-consuming than asking AIs. I'm looking for a browser extension that can:

- Suggest relevant forums (e.g., Stack Exchange sites, subreddits) to post my question.
- Convert a question that I asked AIs (e.g., Phind, Copilot) into a question tailored for specific forums.
- Post the question with a click of a button without leaving the AI interface.

Are there any existing tools that meet these requirements?